# Design pattern for similar functions with lambdas

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns

I am trying to figure out a way or a pattern to simplify my Service class and make it very adjustable. My aim would be for the method in Service class to be accessed for example with lambdas or Predicates.

```
class Client {
  @RequestLine("something/a")
  public A fetchA() {}

  @RequestLine("something/b")
  public B fetchB() {}

  //... lots of similar methods

  @RequestLine("something/z")
  public Z fetchZ() {}
}

class Service {

 Client client;

 public void fixA(){
  client.fetchA();
  method();
 }

 public void fixB(){
  client.fetchB();
  method();
 }

// ... lots of similar methods

 public void fixZ(){
  client.fetchZ();
  method();
 }

 void method() {}

}
```

So my point how I could change it so it would use lambdas or something that would leave my Service class with one of the "fix" methods but it would know what I need to fetch from my Client.

If this question is bad and does not comply with rules here then please point me in the right direction as I am lost.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit what it is that you're asking for? You have a `Client` class with some public methods and you have a `Service` class through which you want to call `Client`'s methods, making sure that you call `Service.method()` after each one. Are you saying that you want to simplify the code within `Service` so that it "knows" which `Client.fetch*` method to call based on the `Service.fix*` method?

Comment: I would like to have one fix() method that takes some arguments like lambdas or predicates or something (I don't have many ideas on that one) and that it would know which Client method to call. Maybe calling specific client method should be passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to pass the call to your client as an argument to the method of your service. You'd need to use generics:

```
class Service {

    Client client;

    public <T> void fix(Function<Client, T> clientCall) {

        T result = clientCall.apply(client);

        // Do something with result

        method();
    }

}
```

You would need to call your service `fix` method as follows:

```
service.fix(Client::fetchA);
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess what you want is

```
class Service {

    private Client client;

    public void fix(Consumer<Client> consumer){
        consumer.accept(client);
        method();
    }

    private void method() {}
}
```

that you can call using

```
service.fix(Client::fetchB);
```

Answer (score 1):

This question may be somewhat opinion based but let’s give it a try.

From my point of view the first design flaw you made is to put all the `fetchXYZ` methods into one client. You could create an interface `Client` that might look like this

```
interface Client<T> {
  T fetch();
}
```

And create implementations of this interface like this:

```
public class ClientA implements Client<A> {
  @RequestLine(”something/a“)
  public A fetch() {
    // do fetch stuff
  }
}
```

You could store instances of the client implementations locally in a map or use a Factory pattern to create the right client depending on your input. And finally the `fix` method in your service might look like this:

```
public void fix(String clientType) {
  // returns instance of ClientA for ’a‘ for example
  final Client client = getClientForType(clientType);
  client.fetch();
  method();
}
```

There‘re probably plenty of ways to solve your requirements and this is just one of them.

I personally don’t like the idea of passing the client function as parameter to your method (although you asked for it) as in your current design `Client` has different responsibilities (fetches `A`, `B` and so on). Using lambdas actually enforces this flaw and furthermore hides what `Client` actually does.

Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the point of Service is to be a facade over the Client. If that is the case with your example and you dont want to expose Clent class to the caller of Service you can go with single method and an enum like this:

```
public class Service {
    Client client = new Client();

    public enum FixType{
        A(Client::fetchA),
        B(Client::fetchB),
        Z(Client::fetchZ);

        private Consumer<Client> c = null;

        private FixType(Consumer<Client> c) {
            this.c = c;
        }

        private void fix(Client client) {
            c.accept(client);
        }
    }

    public void fix(FixType ft) {
        ft.fix(client);
        method();
    }

    void method() {}
}
```

And call `fix` by passing one of enums:

```
new Service().fix(Service.FixType.B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
class Client {

  public A fetch (String identifier) {

    ArrayList<String> identifiers = ...;

    // validate user-provided identifier here

    if (___.equals(identifier)) {
      // specific code for each identifier
    } else if {
      // ...etc.
    }

  }
}

class Service {

  Client client;

  public void fix (String identifier){
    client.fetch(identifier);
    method();
  }

  void method() {}

}
```